# Сложные UI элементы\анимации

Tags: android, android-sdk, material-design, android-animation

Изредка бегло мониторю состояние рынка, и часто встречаю в вакансиях примерно следующее: "Отличное знание `UI` и создание собственных сложных UI компонентов и анимаций"

Поскольку все книги по `Android` разработке ооочень быстро устаревают, и простые действия с `View` (такие как скейл, исчезание, поворот на n-градусов и етс) как бы - просты.

Так вот вопрос состоит в том, как приступить к изучению кастомного `UI` и кастомных анимаций? На порталах вроде `StartAndroid` я находил лишь простые примеры, и на самом деле есть множество способов анимирования.

Однако многие из которых устарели или являются слишком простыми, не актуальными.

Мне бы хотелось перенять опыт, узнать - какими инструментами, и как происходит построение грамотной верстки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

по UI и UX много информации в статьях и блогах. вот список статей, которые считаю полезными:

неплохая статья по основам [UX](https://medium.com/ux-in-motion/creating-usability-with-motion-the-ux-in-motion-manifesto-a87a4584ddc), чтобы знать что можно сделать, как это сделать правильно;

[гайдлайны](https://material.io/guidelines/) матириал - тоже советую ознакомиться

либы, фреймворки от гугл:

[Transition API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4L4fLrWDvAU),

[physics-based animation library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNcODK-Ju0g),

[AnimatedVectorDrawable](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html)

вот примеры сложных UI с кодом:

https://proandroiddev.com/implementing-complex-animations-in-android-full-working-code-41979cc2369e

https://yalantis.com/blog/how-we-created-a-multiselection-solution-for-android/?utm_source=androiddevdigest

https://yalantis.com/blog/develop-filter-animation-kotlin-android/

http://saulmm.github.io/from-design-to-android-part1

https://medium.com/@saulmm2/from-design-to-android-part-2-2a6c141547d9

http://frogermcs.github.io/Instagram-with-Material-Design-concept-is-getting-real-the-summary/

полезные блоги и статьи:

[серия статей по переходам между экранами](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html)

[про кастомные вьюхи, основы](https://hackernoon.com/android-draw-a-custom-view-ef79fe2ff54b)

[неплохая статья про работу с ресурсами](https://academy.realm.io/posts/android-resources-refactoring/)

Comment: к тому времени, когда ответили на этот вопрос, я уже сменил направление и перешел в фронтенд разработку)
за потраченное время и такую большую подборку, поставлю как ответ.

Comment: @Silento поддерживаю засчитать как ответ - хотя сам нашел неслабую подборку UI - все равно себе в коллекцию запишу ссылки из ответа.
моя ссылочка: https://www.uplabs.com/material